# Selecting Sprites, that were created "ingame"

Tags: c++, stl, sprite, sfml

I've have been searching the web thoroughly for several days now and could't come up with any solution for the following problem: It's about C++ and SFML 2.1. I would like being able to select "ingame"-generated single Sprites by middle(button)-clicking on them (and later doing something with them). If there are more than one sprite at any given position (overlapping), than I would like to select the topmost one. I'm using a list and whenever I try to select any Sprite, only the one, that has been created as last, "reacts" correctly (that is printig a console text). Many thanks in advance for any help.

Full code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(1000, 600));
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(100,80,100,100));
    rectangle.setPosition(0, 0);

    sf::Sprite newSprite;

    sf::FloatRect rightBound = rectangle.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::FloatRect unitrect = newSprite.getGlobalBounds();

    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600), "Map");
    mMainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::Texture unittexture;
    unittexture.loadFromFile("warrior.png");

    std::list<sf::Sprite> EnemyList;
    std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator EnemyIt;

    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mMainWindow.close();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Middle)
                if(newSprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow))))
                    std::cout << "Unit selected" << std::endl;

            if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    sf::Vector2f mousecoords(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y)));
                    EnemyList.remove_if([=](sf::Sprite unitsprite){return unitsprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousecoords); });
                }
            if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                    if (rectangle.getGlobalBounds().contains(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow))))        
                    {
                        newSprite.setTexture(unittexture);
                        newSprite.setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).x,sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).y);
                        EnemyList.push_back(newSprite);
                    }
        }

        for(EnemyIt = EnemyList.begin();EnemyIt != EnemyList.end();EnemyIt++)
        {
            mMainWindow.draw(*EnemyIt);
        }
        mMainWindow.display();
        mMainWindow.clear(sf::Color(0, 200, 0, 255));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When checking the middle mouse event, you only seem to check if the click was within the bounds of the newest sprite created. Is that on purpose?

Comment: For the moment it is on purpose, because I don't know better. But I would like it to check for being within the bounds of the "topmost" sprite.

Comment: Wait, so what is the problem? "I'm using a list and whenever I try to select any Sprite, only the one, that has been created as last, "reacts" correctly..." Seems like only checking the newest sprite would cause this, but it's on purpose?

Comment: Ok, no it's not really on purpose :-) It's only to show how far I got. (not very far :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event loop, you have the following code:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Middle)
    if(newSprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow))))
        std::cout << "Unit selected" << std::endl;
```

`newSprite` is set to the sprite you added last to the list, so the only sprite you're checking for middle clicks on is the last sprite you added to the list. If you want to check for clicks on all of the sprites, you'll have to loop through the list and check for a click on every sprite.

Since you want only the top-most sprite to be selected, though, it's a little trickier. First you have to define what you mean by "top-most"; if you mean the unit that is visually "on top" of the other, just take the last enemy in the list that contains the mouse. The reason this works is that SFML just sticks the image on top of whatever's already rendered; that is, if two sprites are rendered on top of each other, the one drawn last is shown on top. Since you're drawing the list front-to-back, the back-most elements will be the ones drawn on the top.

Roughly, it should look something like this:

```
if(event == middle mouse click) {
    for(sprite in list.reverse()) {
        if(mouse in sprite.bounds) {
            //clicked sprite
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't a particularly robust way of doing things, though. Logic should not be tied to rendering; we're depending on a particular order of drawing to achieve the correct effect. You should probably figure out a better way to define the order in which the units are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Middle)
            {
            for(EnemyIt = EnemyList.begin();EnemyIt != EnemyList.end();EnemyIt++)
                if (newSprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow))))
                {
                EnemyList.reverse();
                std::cout << "Inside Sprite " << std::endl;
                }
            }
```

Now I have this so far, but it seems impossible to tell him not to care only about the last created sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, many thanks.
Just for the record my solution:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    sf::RectangleShape maprect;
    maprect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(500, 500));
    maprect.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,255,255));

    sf::Sprite newSprite;

    sf::FloatRect mapbound = maprect.getGlobalBounds();

    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Map");
    mMainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::Texture unittexture;
    unittexture.loadFromFile("warrior.png");

    std::list<sf::Sprite> EnemyList;
    std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator EnemyIt;

    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                {
                mMainWindow.close();
                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)    
                        {
                            newSprite.setTexture(unittexture);
                            newSprite.setPosition(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).x,sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).y))); 
                            EnemyList.push_back(newSprite);
                            std::cout << EnemyList.size() << std::endl;
                        }
            for (auto &EnemyIt = EnemyList.rbegin(); EnemyIt != EnemyList.rend(); ++EnemyIt)
                if (EnemyIt->getGlobalBounds().contains(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y))))
                    if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                        if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)

                        {
                            EnemyList.rbegin();
                            std::cout << EnemyIt->getPosition().x << std::endl;
                            std::cout << EnemyIt->getPosition().y << std::endl;
                            break;
                        }

        }
        mMainWindow.clear();
        mMainWindow.draw(maprect);

        for(EnemyIt = EnemyList.begin();EnemyIt != EnemyList.end();++EnemyIt)
            {
                mMainWindow.draw(*EnemyIt);
            }
        mMainWindow.display();


    }

    return 0;
}
```